# Why separator inset value affecting table header title offset in iOS?

Tags: ios, uistoryboard

In storyboard, I have separator inset value set to custom(left = 30) for UITableView. It moves the tableView separator line to the right by 30. In addition, it is also shifting the tableView header title text by 30 such that Separator line and header text are left aligned to each other. How can I only change the separator line offset without affecting the offset of headerTitle text? Why is separator offset affecting the header title offset?